# "Heat up" or "heat"

Tags: word-choice, differences, phrasal-verbs

It seems they have same meaning but why are we using the phrasal verb? Or they have same meaning?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and re-format it appropriately? It's not easy to read it as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Heat up* can be used, as *heat* too, to mean "make or become hot or warm"; *heat up* has also additional meanings, though:

- [of a person] become excited or impassioned
- become more intense and exciting
- [archaic] inflame; excite

When you say "the action really begins to heat up," it doesn't mean the environment's temperature is getting higher.

Comment: In your last example, I think many if not most people would say the action "hots up", rather that "heats up".

Comment: @Fumblefingers, if they do say that, I hope you slap them.

Comment: @Hellion: Certainly not! People say what they say. Our primary job here is to ascertain what people actually do say and circulate that information as best we can, not tell them what they *should* have said. For what it's worth, Googling "**pace heats up**" gets 21K hits, against 30K hits for "**pace hots up**", so I think it's safe to say both usages are perfectly "standard".

Comment: _Hot up_ is used in British English.

Comment: @fumblefingers, I disagree almost completely; if we only report without advising, we are doing a poor job indeed.

Comment: Oh, the old descriptivism vs. prescriptivism quarrel!

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I suspected it might be a Briticism, but couldn't see any easy way to establish that. To my ear, *the pace heats up* sounds decidedly odd, but I guess to Americans it actually sounds "correct", not just "tolerable". If nothing else, that shows how unwise it would be to follow Hellion's prescription and start telling people which version they *should* be using.